# Why XKB shift levels are 1 (none), 2 (Shift), 3 (AltGr), 5, and not 0, 1, 2, 4?

Tags: keyboard, history, xkb

XKB uses the following scheme for shift levels (as can be seen in various `/usr/share/X11/xkb/` files):

- level_name[Level1] = "Base";
- level_name[Level2] = "Shift";
- level_name[Level3] = "Alt Base";
- level_name[Level4] = "Shift Alt";
- level_name[Level5] = "X";
- level_name[Level6] = "X Shift";
- level_name[Level7] = "X Alt Base";
- level_name[Level8] = "X Shift Alt";

I.e. 1-based numbering (this particular list is from `/usr/share/X11/xkb/types/level5` definitions).
But it seems like it would make a better sense for 0-based numbering, like:

- level_name[Level0] = "Base";
- level_name[Level1] = "Shift";
- level_name[Level2] = "Alt Base";
- level_name[Level3] = "Shift Alt"; (i.e. 1 + 2)
- level_name[Level4] = "X";
- level_name[Level5] = "X Shift"; (1 + 4)
- level_name[Level6] = "X Alt Base"; (2 + 4)
- level_name[Level7] = "X Shift Alt"; (1 + 2 + 4)

I.e. like a bit field. Instead, they use 1-based numbering. What were the reasons behind the choice? It seems like 0-based numbering is common in the Linux world, and in this particular case it would be sensible and intuitive.

Comment: Where is numbering used in this context? Where do you get the `1 = none` from? Also, note that 0-based numbering is never intuitive unless one is very used to working with computers.

Comment: To my experience, it is very common in the linux world to mix both numberings like the hardware UART0 is called COM1 and so on. It confuses me every now and then.

Comment: @terdon this scheme is used in XKB, ex., take a look at `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/` directory, there are symbols files named `level2`..`level5` describing various options for level-shifting keys (`ISO_Level3_Shift` name is commonly used there too). There is also `/usr/share/X11/xkb/types/level5` file with a list of level names like `level_name[Level1] = "Base"; level_name[Level2] = "Shift";`, etc.

Comment: Please add this to your question since it really isn't obvious at all. That said, I doubt you can really make this answerable here. It sounds like something you would have to ask of whoever developed this and there really isn't any objective way of choosing whether 0-based or 1-based is better for something involving humans and not only machines.

Comment: @terdon added clarifications, thanks.